# Перенесённые комментарии показываются как исправленные

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, инструменты-модератора

При переносе ответа в комментарий, у получившихся комментариев (из ответа и из комментариев к нему, если перенос был с комментариями) показывается значок, что комментарий был изменён, хотя это не так:

> [image: скриншот бывшего ответа]
>
> [image: и комментария к нему]

Не пойму, это намеренно сделано, или баг?